# How do i save a text with some linked words, with Flex/PHP in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a CMS where i can insert texts with direct links to my favorite sites, to be viewed in the FrontPage, but i just want to show the name of them (bold or colored) and not the URL. How can i do it!?
I´m using a DB with some other info and works great, but I'm not achieving this part. any solution!?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: What output are you getting ? And what is your desired/expected output ?

Comment: <a href="http://www.google.pt" target="_blank"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Some</span></a> text Some text    --- i´m putting this and getting the same!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);    
    return $matches[0];
}

$str = '<a href="google.pt" target="_blank"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Some</span></a>';
$txt = getTextBetweenTags($str, "a");
echo $txt;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but with that, every time i want to change the text/links in the CMS is not going to work because i have to change this PHP again!! What i think i need is that the output text area do that "conversion"; right!?

Comment: Right. Before you set the output let the function convert the string and then echo it.

Comment: sorry .. I understand the idea but how do I do that!?